# Setting a property value using reflection throwing an exception

Tags: c#, maui, system.reflection, community-toolkit-mvvm

Im using the Microsoft Community MVVM package within my MAUI app. It's working well, but I've hit an issue.

Part of my UI modifies a structure which sends a message to the view model. This works fine. However, when I try to modify the structure, I'm getting an exception (`Object does not match target type.`)

The code leading up to the exception looks like this

```
messenger.Register<ObjectMessage>(this, (o, t) =>
{
     switch (t.Sender)
     {
          case "Changes":
              try
              {
                   var prop = Content.Structure.GetType().GetProperty((string)t.Message);
                   prop.SetValue(t.Value, Convert.ChangeType(t.Value, prop.PropertyType));
               }
               catch(Exception ex)
               {
 #if DEBUG
                   Console.WriteLine($"Exception - ex.Message = {ex.Message}");
 #endif
               }
               HasChanges = Content.Structure != DupeContent.Structure;
               break;
      }
 });
```

I've tried a number of different ways to assign the value to the property, but always get the exception.

`t.Value` and `t.Message` are of type `object`

Comment: `t.Value` and `t.Message` are of type `object` - This isn't a helpful statement because `object` is [an alias for System.Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/reference-types), and ["all classes in .NET are derived from Object"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object?view=net-7.0). What do you get when you do `t.Value.GetType()` or `t.Message.GetType()`?

Comment: Is the error occurring in `Convert.ChangeType` or in `SetValue`? If necessary, split into two separate statements to isolate the problem.

Answer (score 2):

The first argument to `SetValue` should be the actual object you're trying to modify. In this case, it appears to be `Content.Structure` (since that's what you called `GetType()` on). Try using that object as the first argument:

```
prop.SetValue(Content.Structure, Convert.ChangeType(t.Value, prop.PropertyType));
```